# angular js - unable to access objects pushed to array in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my controller

```
angular.module("app").controller('myController', ['$scope', '$filter','$rootScope','contentService','$location','$anchorScroll', function ($scope, $filter,$rootScope,contentService,$location,$anchorScroll) {

$scope.searchContents = [] ;

var filterList = function (list, keyword) {
    return $filter('filter')(list, keyword);
};

var addToSearchContents = function (list,type){
    _.each(list,function(item){
        item.type = type;
        $scope.searchContents.push(item);
    });     
};

$scope.init = function(){
    var str = $location.absUrl();
    $scope.searchKeyword = str.substring(str.indexOf("=") + 1,str.length);

    !_.isEmpty($scope.searchKeyword)
    {
        // get all songs
        contentService.getAllSongs().then(function (result) {
            var filteredSongs = filterList(result.data.songs, $scope.searchKeyword);
            addToSearchContents(filteredSongs,"song");
        });

        // get all people
        contentService.getAllPeople().then(function (result) {
            var filteredPeople = filterList(result.data.people, $scope.searchKeyword);
            addToSearchContents(filteredPeople,"people");
        });           

        _.each($scope.searchContents,function(item){

             alert("item -> "+item.type);
        });
    }
};

$scope.init();

}]);
```

`Items(objects)` are added to the variable `$scope.searchContents` in `addToSearchContents` but if i try to access/iterate after all objects that are pushed to  `$scope.searchContents` with `_.each` it seems to `null`. But i can access all the contents in HTML page with `ng-repeat`  but not in controller. I am puzzled, am i missing something.

Comment: Seems that you're missing a `if(` before testing `!_.isEmpty($scope.searchKeyword)`. An other thing : use angular built-in functions instead of underscore.

Comment: @ mguimard - thanks for pointing out `if`, and i have tried angular inbuilt function instead of underscore js...still not able to iterate over contents added to array inside controller

Comment: can you provide [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)?

Comment: `contentService.getAllSongs()` and `contentService.getAllPeople()` seems to be asynchronous stuff. You're iterating the `$scope.searchContents` whereas it's not filled yet.

Comment: see about [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another variant, also with [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all):

```
$q.all([
    // get all songs
    contentService.getAllSongs().then(function (result) {
        var filteredSongs = filterList(result.data.songs, $scope.searchKeyword);
        addToSearchContents(filteredSongs,"song");
    }),

    // get all people
    contentService.getAllPeople().then(function (result) {
        var filteredPeople = filterList(result.data.people, $scope.searchKeyword);
        addToSearchContents(filteredPeople,"people");
    })]).then(function(){         
        // here all items already added so we can iterate it
        _.each($scope.searchContents,function(item){
            alert("item -> "+item.type);
        });
    });
```

Comment: When the `_.each...` is called, maybe the `getAllSongs()` is not resolved yet.

Comment: @Joy, nope, `_.each` called after all promisses in `$q.all` resolved, so `getAllSongs` would be resolved, and `then` function also would be resolved. I you see a bit more, you can see that you have the same code, but i put `then` functions inside `$q.all` :-)

Comment: @Grundy nd @ Joy - Yes due to async call to get json data, contents weren't not filled in the array until its resolved...thanks alot..:)

Answer (score 2):

You got the error because when you call `_.each($scope.searchContents...`, the data has not arrived from the async calls. `addToSearchContents` is not executed yet.

Use [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q#all), which combines all promises into on giant one. And then do something after all promises are resolved.

> Note: remember to inject the service `$q` to your controller.

```
$q.all([
    contentService.getAllSongs(),
    contentService.getAllPeople()
]).then(function (result) { 
    // `result` is an array containing the results from the promises.

    var filteredSongs = filterList(result[0].data.songs, $scope.searchKeyword);
    addToSearchContents(filteredSongs,"song");

    var filteredPeople = filterList(result[1].data.people, $scope.searchKeyword);
    addToSearchContents(filteredPeople,"people");

    _.each($scope.searchContents,function(item){
        alert("item -> "+item.type);
    });
});
```

I do not have your coding context, so a similar [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pbhkuw5L/) is created for you. It illustrates the same idea.